# mysql variable with @variables for calculated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query where I need to calculate values like `ROUND(SUM(temp.total_pq),2)` multiple times, so I defined variables to avoid repeating them.

But the line 5 in the query returns wrong value in the results. The value for `@diff_client_partner_qtty := ROUND((@partner_qtty_all_runs - @client_qtty_all_runs), 2) AS diff_client_partner_qtty` is always NULL the first time I run and thereafter always 84.

I asked the in-house DBA and he says I should not use variables in my query like this because the order in which mysql will set values for the variable is not predictable and hence I may get NULL value.

But why? Also can someone please propose then another way whereby I can avoid rewriting `ROUND(SUM(temp.total_pq),2)` multiple times other than a subquery. I would prefer to avoid a subquery because I think even in its current form query is not that readable.

```
SELECT temp.dtaccounted                                                                   AS accounting_period,
  @partner_qtty_all_runs := ROUND(SUM(temp.total_pq),2)                                   AS partner_qtty_all_runs,
  ROUND(temp.mmq,2)                                                                       AS mopay_qtty,
  @client_qtty_all_runs     := ROUND(SUM(temp.total_cq),2)                                AS client_qtty_all_runs,
  @diff_client_partner_qtty := ROUND((@partner_qtty_all_runs - @client_qtty_all_runs), 2) AS diff_client_partner_qtty,
  @partner_gtv              := ROUND(temp.total_pq_gtv, 2)                                AS partner_gtv,
  @client_gtv               := ROUND(temp.total_cq_gtv,2)                                 AS client_gtv,
  @diff_client_partner_gtv  := ROUND((@partner_gtv - @client_gtv), 2)                     AS diff_client_partner_gtv,
  temp.stariffcurrency                                                                    AS tariffcurrency,
  ROUND(@diff_client_partner_gtv * ffactor, 2)                                            AS diff_client_partner_gtv_eur,
  temp.scountry                                                                           AS country,
  temp.spartnererpid                                                                      AS partner_erp_id,
  c.name                                                                                  AS partner_name,
  temp.nproducttype                                                                       AS product,
  temp.capping
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(npartnerquantity)          AS total_pq,
    SUM(nmindmaticsquantity)             AS mmq,
    SUM(nclientquantity)                 AS total_cq,
    SUM(dgrosstariff * npartnerquantity) AS total_pq_gtv,
    SUM(dgrosstariff * nclientquantity)  AS total_cq_gtv,
    nrun,
    vb.scountry,
    vb.spartnererpid,
    dtaccounted,
    stariffcurrency,
    vb.nproducttype,
    cq.bisenabled AS capping
  FROM report_table vb,
    client_table cq
  WHERE vb.accperiod > '2013-12-01'
  AND vb.partnerid = cq.partnerid
  AND vb.scountry      = cq.scountry
  AND vb.nproducttype  = cq.nproducttype
  AND (cq.dtvalidto   IS NULL
  OR cq.dtvalidto      > vb.accperiod)
  GROUP BY scountry,
    nproducttype,
    partnerid,
    nrun,
    accperiod
  ) temp,
  customer c,
  currency_conversion cc
WHERE temp.partnerid = c.erp_id
AND temp.total_pq       <> temp.total_cq
AND cc.scurrencyfrom     = temp.stariffcurrency
AND cc.scurrencyto       = 'EUR'
AND cc.dtrefdate         = temp.accperiod
GROUP BY temp.scountry,
  temp.partnerid,
  c.name,
  temp.nproducttype,
  temp.accperiod
ORDER BY temp.accperiod,
  temp.scountry,
  temp.partnerid,
  temp.nproducttype,
  temp.capping \G;
```

Comment: Why?  That's the way it is.  Use the language as written.  However, this is the first time I've seen where the ordering really does make a difference, so it is a very useful example.

Comment: thanks, apart from using a subquery, do you see any "straight forward" chance of avoiding having to repeat each calculated value in this query? Also, is using a variable like this in a query is not recommended at all (i mean even when simpler arithmetic like a + b is involved)?